# Use different operator based on condition in Python

Tags: python

In my current project I have some duplicated code and I am looking for a possibility to remove it. I have a boolean called `forward`. If it's true, I want to add days to a datetime, if not I want to subtract days:

```
if forward:
    day = today + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
else:
    day = today - datetime.timedelta(days=3)
```

Is there any possibility to do that in less than these 4 lines?

Comment: day = today + datetime.timedelta(days=3 if forward else -3)  .


# timedelta works with negative numbers as well which is same as using -timedelta

Comment: `(operator.add if forward else operator.sub)(today, datetime.timedelta(days=3))`… But is that really more readable…?!

Comment: There are shorter ways, but none are clearer than what you already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's not statically `3`, multiply with -1 or +1 depending on direction?

```
n_days = 10
day = today + datetime.timedelta(days=(n_days * (1 if forward else -1)))
```